# how to add text for first and last of index in ruby

Tags: ruby

add text for first and last of index in ruby
here is my Array

```
 array ["name", "we", "Go", "live"]
```

result

```
 :name, :we, :Go, :live
```

Comment: That example doesn't really show what you're wanting to do, IMO..can you try to elaborate and clarify a little more what your question is, what you're trying to do, and any code you may have tried?

Comment: array ["name", "we", "Go", "live"].join(', ')

Comment: butt the result just like: name, we, Go, live but what I want is  :name, :we, :Go, :live

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
["name", "we", "Go", "live"].map { |item| ":#{item}" }.join(", ")
#=> ":name, :we, :Go, :live"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
["name", "we", "Go", "live"].map &:to_sym
=> [:name, :we, :Go, :live]
```